# Unable to load CSV file into MS Azure

Tags: azure, csv, azure-files

I'm using Microsoft Azure,  Mobile Apps.
I am trying to load an EasyTable from data contained in a CSV file.
I press the "Add from CSV" and select my file.
However, if the table already exists, I get an error saying the table already exists.
If the table does not exist, then it is created successfully, but then I get an error saying "Could not find name,dob,location columns on Users table"

My CSV file first row has all the column names (name dob location).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: there can be issues with csv separators like , vs ;

Comment: check csv data, there is a chance that csv some row may have less number of column in compare to that table.

Comment: Here is the entire csv test file: (Sorry about the formatting...)
name,birthDatePlace,height
Acker Edward , ,
Acker Erin (I) , 14 November 1978  Minneapolis  Minnesota  USA ,
Acker Eugene (II) , 13 May 1889  Stockholm  Stockholm  Sweden ,
Acker Iris (I) , ,
The error message is:
Could not find name,birthDatePlace,height columns on Users table.